# "Well" building special function clarification

Tags: san-juan

*Well* card text:

> During the producer phase, if the owner of a well produces at least 2
>   goods, he draws an additional card from the card supply, adding it to
>   his hand. It matters not whether he is the producer or not.

Let's say i have two production buildings.
The first is busy (one card face down on it), second one is empty.
Producer phase starts, i'm not the producer, so i produce an additional good on 
my second building.

So I produced **one good at this specific phase** and I'm currently **producing two goods in total** as I have 2 busy production buildings at the end of the phase.

**Question: should I draw an additonal card in this case?**

---

Edit:

*Another way to formulate the question would be:*

Which one of this rewritten rule corresponds to the rule? :

1. During the producer phase, if the owner of a well produces at least 2 **new** goods, he draws an additional card from the card supply, adding it to his hand.
2. During the producer phase, if the total number of goods lying on production buildings is at least 2, he draws an additional card from the card supply, adding it to his hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not draw an extra card.

The [rules](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=136) say the following under the Producer role:

> If a player has no empty production buildings, he produces no goods in this round.

Consequently it's established that the production of a good is dependent on the availability of a building to do so. If you only have one production building free then you can only produce at most one good, and so you do not qualify for the Well bonus.

---

*In answer to the edited part of the question:*

The correct interpretation of the rule is rule 1 - i.e. the goods must be new.

I think your misunderstanding is shown by the following statement "I'm currently producing two goods in total". This is not correct - you have produced one good already, and in the current phase you are producing one new good.

Note that to produce two goods in a single Producer phase you must either be the Producer, or have an Aquaduct built.

Comment: I do think too that you do not draw an extra card but I am not completely convinced by the explanation.
Maybe it's just my english because "during" + "produce" suggest that the 2 products **have to** be produced at that specific phase (and not spread on multiple phases), is that right?

Comment: @kraymer Yes, you're right - "During *the* producer phase" implies that the following events have to happen within a single producer phase (i.e. the production of at least two goods). The goods have to be new, cards already on top of production buildings have already been produced (i.e. they represent goods, not the production of goods).

Comment: Thanks, I mistakenly played with rule 2 yesterday and the Well was a hell of a card :D